# grunt-ng-annotate adding source files for angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, gulp, ng-annotate

I am using **grunt-ng-annotate** for automatically injecting the dependencies in order to prevent them from getting minified. I have used the below task:

```
ngAnnotate: {
        app:{
                files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['**/*.js', '!**/*.annotated.js'],
                ext: '.annotated.js',
                extDot: 'last'
              }]
            }
    }
```

But My grunt task is not able to pick up any file:

Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task

```
No files provided to the ngAnnotate task.

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2016-02-24 16:14:31 UTC)
loading tasks    234ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 96%
ngAnnotate:dist    8ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
Total 243ms
```

I have used a fresh yeoman generator and generated a project and added /* @ngInject */ above one of the controllers

Below is my folder structure
[image]